# Calling smart contract on private Geth network using Esp32/arduino

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, geth-clique

I'm trying to call smart contract deployed on private geth blockchain. I couldn't find relevant library on ESP32/Arduino to interact with smart contract. What should I do?

Comment: I got this link https://github.com/gusgorman402/ESP8266_Geth from this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/29524/sign-raw-transaction-offline-with-c-on-arduino.